# Package imports fails "Target of URI doesn't exist: import 'package:supercharged/supercharged.dart';"

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to import a package using flutter and I get the following error:

`"Target of URI doesn't exist: import 'package:supercharged/supercharged.dart';"`

I want to import: [supercharged package Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged/install)

I am adding the following import in the file;

`import 'package:supercharged/supercharged.dart';`

And my `pubspect.yaml` looks like this:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  line_awesome_flutter: 1.0.1
  simple_animations: 2.2.2
  sa_v1_migration: 1.1.2
  supercharged: 1.10.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
 
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I've tried `pub get` and `pub upgrade`

Comment: did u try pub get?

Comment: After pub get and flutter clean, simply restart the editor.

Comment: You can upvote if the answer is helped :) 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428543/10659482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stefano Leone mentioned, if restarting the editor does not help, there may be an issue related installation of your IDE. So you can try to re-install VSCode or Android Studio.

Here is a similar issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49702).